# Can we call twitter API directly from browser?

Tags: javascript, security, twitter, oauth

I have seen twitter REST API need a complicate oauth header and it recommend to be called on server side

Which is I wonder that, is it possible that I could call those REST API from browser with JavaScript

What I understand is OAuth header of twitter need signature that must be signed with consumer secret (not app secret)

I want to know are there anyway I could do it on client side?
And what would be the problem if I expose that consumer secret (not app secret) on my site? Or are there a way to call those API without oauth_signature in header

Comment: If you're using Chrome, [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) will allow you to construct REST requests using your browser as a client.

Comment: That said, if you're looking to make the REST calls from client-side javascript on your site (which it sounds like you are), I would recommend that you **not** do that. Giving out your API key will allow anyone with the ability to use view-source the credentials to do anything that you gave the API key permission to do, while appearing to be you. This is a serious security problem in 99% of cases.

Comment: @Actorclavilis As I said, in twitter there are consumer secret which IS NOT app secret. It is a difference key so I'm not sure what security problem it could be leads to. I'm surely not let app secret exist in client. But for consumer secret I was tempted to

Comment: Rule of thumb: If anything is "secret" it should never be in public domain. You can use services like https://webtask.io or AWS Lambda to build and deploy your server side fairly quickly.

Comment: @Abhishrek Surely as the rule state that but for the performance and cost I would not like to do unnecessary security (lambda is not actually free it subtly cost you all data transfer)

Comment: @Abhishrek And, again, as I said, It seem unnecessary because it is not app secret. consumer secret is not the same key as app secret. expose consumer secret seem like reducing security to the same level as facebook. I just want to make sure that it will not more than that

Answer (score 0):

create a Server to call the API, don't directly call it from the browser

Comment: Yeah, for 5 years I try to thought their should be, even more so in this era of decentralize and web3, twitter seem to be close themselves too much in this way